# Crypt.crypt(password,salt) for IOS returns wrong value

Tags: ios, hash, salt, crypt

I am trying to create Crypt hash in ios by using the following code

```
#include <unistd.h>


const char *password = "password";
const char *salt = "$6$12$Z1NO9zPeobe2lNRI7VGoV2yeD7zZ";
const char *cryptedText =crypt(password, salt);

NSLog(@"Output :%s",cryptedText);
```

Here is the OutPut: `$6FMi11BJFsAc`
which is 15 character long hash

but i am suppose to get result as `$6$12$EmCj0n6cuRQPJkS9i8q9F9JzlbErFPXFeUH7zwAT1yfBuwP7L60bNzWNvizJifxL6Dsd2mLIOFfcHyCbRoYSd0`,

i am getting the expected result from android code, and the android code is as follow

Export package `import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Crypt;`

here is the code:

```
String password_encrypt = Crypt.crypt("password",
                "$6$12$Z1NO9zPeobe2lNRI7VGoV2yeD7zZ");
printf("Output :" + password_encrypt);
```

Output :`$6$12$EmCj0n6cuRQPJkS9i8q9F9JzlbErFPXFeUH7zwAT1yfBuwP7L60bNzWNvizJifxL6Dsd2mLIOFfcHyCbRoYSd0`

Can anyone suggest me what is the solution to make it working and that should be matching with android hash value. which algorithm i should used to get it work in IOS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider presenting a complete example of the input of both what you expect and what you are getting along with actual iOS code. Offhand I would not expect 96 characters, you should get $6$ + salt + $ + 86 characters of base64 encoded hash. See the crypt [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/Crypt.html#crypt(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: In general if you expect good answers you need to provide a better and more complete questions. Supply actual code, the input and output data along with what was expected and what the error is--exactly.

Comment: I have edited the question with values and salt i am using and the actual and expected result, suggest me if you have any solution regarding this.

Comment: Not really an answer but the current best practice is to use PBKDF2, see WikiPedia [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)

Comment: OK, let me give a try, Thanks :)

Comment: To be more clear: The current best practice is to use PBKDF2 for deriving an encryption key from a password, the Common Crypto function is: 'CCKeyDerivationPBKDF'. You have to decide on the number of rounds and there is a Common Crypto function `CCCalibratePBKDF` to help determine that. If you are doing something different this may not be the best solution.